# 'User matching query does not exist' when adding a like to database

Tags: python, reactjs, django, next.js, django-rest-framework

As the title says, I'm trying to make a like button as a many to many where if a certain verse(or post) is liked by a certain user, a like is added to the database, and if a user unlikes a verse, a like is deleted from the database. I have deleteUserLike working, but am not able to create a like on the frontend, as when I do I get the error above on the backend, and user_id appears null in the payload under the network tab in dev tools.

VerseCard:

```
    const handleCheckChange = (event) => {
    const { checked } = event.target;
    if (checked) {
      createUserLike({ verseId: id, ...userId });
      console.warn(userId);
    } else {
      const userLike = userLikesArray.find((ul) => ul.verse_id === id);
      if (userLike) {
        deleteUserLike(userLike.id);
      }
    }
  };

  return (

    <>
      <Card className="text-center" style={{ width: '25rem' }}>
        <Card.Header>{firstName} {lastName}</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{verse}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{content}</Card.Text>
          <Card.Footer>{version}</Card.Footer>
          <div style={{
            margin: 'auto',
            display: 'block',
            width: 'fit-content',
          }}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              control={(
                <Checkbox
                  icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
                  checkedIcon={<Favorite />}
                  name="checkedH"
                  checked={!!userLikesArray.find((ul) => id === ul.verse_id)}
                  onChange={handleCheckChange}
                />
                )}
            />
```

userLikeData:

```
    const createUserLike = (userLike) => {
  const userLikeObj = {
    verse_id: Number(userLike.verseId),
    user_id: Number(userLike.userId),
  };
  return fetch(`${clientCredentials.databaseURL}/userlikes`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(userLikeObj),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json());
};
```

user_like view:

```
def create(self, request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.data["user_id"])
    verse = Verse.objects.get(pk=request.data["verse_id"])

    user_like = UserLike.objects.create(
        verse=verse,
        user=user
    )
    serializer = UserLikeSerializer(user_like)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Edit: I have also tried changing userId to user.id in the change handler, although user.id properly shows the current user's id in the console warn.

Comment: Well it means that there is no `User` for the `user_id` in `request.data`.

Comment: Wouldn't the same error appear when testing it in postman if that was the case?

Comment: @Smoothingcube3: normally yes, if you use the same `user_id` and the same (state) of the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but it didn't throw an error when I tested it in postman, used the same `user_id` and everything.